# Process.Kill() doesn't kill the process

Tags: c#, .net

I'm creating a new process to do some long-running action (pdf file conversion). The problem is, if I want to kill that process using its ID, it's not killed, I still see it on the system process' list. Why ?

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "some_file_name";
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "some_dir";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = fullFilePath;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.Start();
    myProcessID = p.Id;

    result.OutputMsg = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); <-- here it waits until operation completes
    result.ErrorMsg = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    p.WaitForExit();
}

...

Process p = Process.GetProcessById(myProcessID);

if (p != null)
   p.Kill();
```

### EDIT

OK, I see it's being killed, but the the conversion still continues. I see that a new process is also being created with name `conhost.exe` (console window host), but don't have its ID. Without it I cannot delete it

Comment: are you sure you're getting the right process?  try stepping through it with the [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Comment: I assume that those two bits of code are on separate threads?

Answer (score 0):

From [the MSDN on Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited.

So, it might be failing for some reason. If you do the suggestion, you can check that